# Dual monitors on different graphics inputs?

Tags: xfce, monitor

Here's my dilemma, I was just running Windows and to run both of my monitors, my secondary monitor was running off of my integrated chip. In my BIOS I set the boot up graphics device to be the integrated. My primary monitor is running off of my XFX R7950. XFCE however, doesn't seem to be able to detect both of my monitors, only the one that is plugged into my integrated chip. My graphics card has two VGA slots though, can I use both at the same time?

Comment: I ended up figuring out how to plug both monitors into the same card, and then using arandr to set them up properly.

Comment: That wasn't how I solved my issue though.

Comment: Then you can describe the solution that worked for you in a separate answer, and then `accept` that.

Answer (score 0):

Xfce `4.10` has only limited support for multiple monitors. The upcoming `4.12` is better at that. You can try installing the (unreleased) 4.12 from [ppa:xubuntu-dev/xfce-4.12](https://launchpad.net/~xubuntu-dev/+archive/xfce-4.12)?

Additionally, you can set up the monitors properly by using `arandr`.